# How to configure heroku application DNS to Godaddy Domain?

Tags: heroku, dns

I have created a heroku application and wants to give domain to it from godaddy.com.

I have configured all three hosts provided by heroku but now I am getting error saying:

> Heroku | No such app
>
> There is no app configured at that hostname.
>
> Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.

I want to know: is there any other way to configure a heroku app?

**UPDATED : New Approach**
[Please use this link for new approach](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) . Accepted answer is old feature.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I used this videocast to set up my GoDaddy domain with Heroku, and it worked perfectly. Very clear and well explained.

Note: Skip the part about `CNAME yourdomain.example.` (note the `.`) and the `heroku addons:add "custom domains"`

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/10/7/heroku_casts_setting_up_custom_domains/

---

To summarize the video:

1. on GoDaddy and create a CNAME with

   ```
   Alias Name: www
   Host Name: proxy.heroku.com
   ```
2. check that your domain has propagated by typing `host www.yourdomain.example` on the command line
3. run `heroku domains:add www.yourdomain.example`
4. run `heroku domains:add yourdomain.example`

It worked for me after these steps. Hope it works for you too!

However, things have changed. Check out this post: [Heroku/GoDaddy: send naked domain to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492563/heroku-godaddy-send-naked-domain-to-www)

Comment: Good post. This is end to end what you need. I was about to post this link.

Comment: I'm new to webdev, so sorry if this question is a little elementary, but do I keep or delete the default CNAME with alias `www` and host name `@`? Edit: Oops, seems like only one can exist.

Comment: As of February 2019, this does not work and GoDaddy will keep any fees you paid them regardless unless you demand a refund very early on. Heroku does keep a list of recommended DNS providers.

More on this here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Answer (score 83):

There are 2 steps you need to perform,

1. Add the custom domains addon and add the domain your going to use, eg `www.mywebsite.example` to your application
2. Go to your domain registrar control panel and set `www.mywebsite.example` to be a CNAME entry to `yourapp.herokuapp.com` assuming you are using the CEDAR stack.
3. There is a third step if you want to use a naked domain, eg `mywebsite.example` when you would have to add the IP addresses of the Heroku load balancers to your DNS for `mywebsite.example`

You can read more about this at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

At a guess you've missed out the first step perhaps?

Following the announcement of Bamboo's EOL `proxy.heroku.com` being retired (September 2014) for Bamboo applications so these should also now use the `yourapp.herokuapp.com` mapping now as well.

Comment: custom domains are now a core feature, so no add-on installation step.

Comment: The CNAME should be set to "[your app].herokuapp.com" (for the Cedar stack, for bamboo use "[your app].heroku.com")

Comment: @JohnBeynon Still would be worthwhile editing your answer, since people are coming to here from Google. *cough*

Comment: This answer doesn't apply anymore

Comment: If you need to redirect your naked domain (example.com) to your heroku app you can use http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect

Comment: There are more options for naked domains here too: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#cname-functionality-at-the-apex. Some DNS providers also provide a "Heroku service" that appear to set it up for you, e.g. https://iwantmyname.com/services/developer/heroku-cloud-hosting-custom-domain

Comment: Please take into account that starting *September 22nd 2014*, Heroku is only supporting `[yourapp].herokuapp.com`. Support for the legacy routing stack `[yourapp].heroku.com` will be dropped.

Comment: this is not their offical blog said to put to domain of your app..it said to put it to proxy.heroku.com instead which didn't work...then began another scavenger hunt...do devs spend over fifty percent of their time on scavenger hunts?

Comment: What if I performed both steps and still get the same error? DNS entry confirmed with host, app config confirmed with heroku domains. What else can I do?

Comment: A few hours later, it started working with no further intervention. Real time.

Answer (score 16):

The trick is to

1. create a CNAME for `www.myapp.example` to `myapp.heroku.com`
2. create a 301 redirection from `myapp.example` to `www.myapp.example`

Comment: I get a 404 for that link. shaks link uses the same approach.

Answer (score 8):

I struggled a lot to resolve it Nothing seemed to work for me.

The steps I followed are mentioned here.

1. Go to your App settings.
2. Click on Add domain.

   [image]
3. A dialog will open & will ask you to enter the desired domain. (Please add it starting with `www` for instance - `www.abcd.example` )

   [image]
4. One added click on Next to move to the next dialog.

   [image]
5. After adding the domain you will get the **DNS** target, Now you need to navigate to GoDaddy and follow the following steps.
6. Navigate to https://dcc.godaddy.com/domains & click on your domain.
7. Once clicked you will navigate to https://dcc.godaddy.com/control/yourdomain/settings
8. Scroll down to the bottom you will see Manage DNS.

   [image]
9. It will navigate you to DNS settings then add the entry similar to mentioned below and delete all other `CNAME` records. Here the value of points is your DNS target that you got in the 4th Step.

   [image]
10. Then after some time your site should be mapped to the Heroku app URL.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, many changes at Heroku. If you're using a Heroku dyno for your webserver, you have to find way to alias from one `DNS` name to another `DNS` name (since each Heroku DNS endpoint may resolve to many IP addrs to dynamically adjust to request loads).

A `CNAME` record is for aliasing `www.example.com` -> `www.example.com.herokudns.com.`

You can't use `CNAME` for a naked domain (`@`), i.e. `example.com` (unless you find a name server that can do `CNAME Flattening` - which is what I did).

But really the easiest solution, that can pretty much be taken care of all in your GoDaddy account, is to create a `CNAME record` that does this: `www.example.com -> www.example.com.herokudns.com`.

And then create a permanent 301 redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

This requires only one heroku custom domain name configured in your heroku app settings: `www.example.com.herokudns.com`. @Jonathan Roy talks about this (above) but provides a bad link.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the naked domain of `your-domain.com` if it is not redirected to the `www.your-domain.com`. Heroku use the `www.yourdomain.com` which act here as a subdomain.  So when you follow the [default instruction](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) to use `your-domain.com` then you will need to assign both of them.

We can actually assign only the naked domain without the `www.your-domain.com`. Use only `your-domain.com` when the domain's dns provider (NameServers) support *[ALIAS or ANAME](https://superuser.com/a/1046499/505363)* for the @ Record to `example.herokuapp.com` without CNAME `www.your-domain.com` to it.

It will let you to point `www.your-domain.com` to other hosting separately (independent).

Answer (score 0):

I pointed the non-www to `54.243.64.13` and the `www.domain.com` to the `alias.herokuapp.com` and all worked nicely.

Found the IP only after pointing `www.domain.com` and then running the dig command on the `www.domain.com` and it showed:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.domain.com. 14400  IN      CNAME   aliasat.herokuapp.com.
aliasat.herokuapp.com. 300 IN CNAME us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com. 60 IN  A       54.235.186.37

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
herokuapp.com.          900     IN      NS      ns-1378.awsdns-44.org.
herokuapp.com.          900     IN      NS      ns-1624.awsdns-11.co.uk.
herokuapp.com.          900     IN      NS      ns-505.awsdns-63.com.
herokuapp.com.          900     IN      NS      ns-662.awsdns-18.net.
```

May not be ideal but worked.

Comment: Your website may go down periodically if you use this solution. The IP may be changed (and it will) which will kill your A record DNS setup. You will have to do this every 2-3 months or after any outage at Heroku. We've been dealing with this and are finally moving over to cloudflare or easyDNS to prevent this.