# Heroku Godaddy naked domain SSL HTTPS

Tags: ssl, heroku, shared-hosting

I'm trying to get my naked domain work. Currently, it's showing this

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478008/heroku-godaddy-naked-domain) answer, and the ones in it. The answers are leading me to believe that if I am using GoDaddy and Heroku, I simply **cannot** use my naked domain. Forwarding from naked domain to full domain only work on HTTP websites. I mean, who still uses HTTP?

What's the easiest way to solve this? Port my domain from GoDaddy to another host that supports ANAME? Is there an option that does not require a large amount of work?