# link a Custom domain to a Heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns

I have set up my application on Heroku. I have also bought a domain name 'tusharm.com' from crazydomains.com I have updated the name servers also on crazydomains.com using Zerigo Dns Addon.

The problem is that when I hit - tusharm.com I get a page from crazydomains.com.
My actual application is staticsite-dev.herokuapp.com

Also I observed that I was getting the following warning when I ran the **Production Check**.

```
Warning 
DNS configuration
Your DNS is not configured correctly. Your domain tusharm.com's CNAME record should point to staticsite-dev.herokuapp.com.
```

Please help! I dont want the money to go wasted for which I bought the domain name.

**EDIT:**

Snapshot of nameservers on Crazydomains.

[image]

Comment: Ok, if zerigo is a heroku dns addon, then you probably just have to wait until changes are propagated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the warning says, you have to set up the dns for your domain so that you have a CNAME record pointing to your heroku app. This is done with your domain registrar, and the process is different from registrar to registrar. Contact support for your registrar, and they will probably be able to assist you.

If you have updated your nameservers already, it might take a few days before the change is reflected.

**Edit**

Also, if you want to be able to use a "naked" domain (without a subdomain, e.g `mydomain.com`, you have to use a registrar that supports an `ALIAS` record type. Otherwise you would have to use `www.yourdomain.com`. Read about it [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains)

**Edit 2**

If you're using an heroku addon, then everything should be handled, and you probably just have to wait.

Comment: Yes, if you have configured it correctly. It is not uncommon that it can take a couple of days. If you post your Zone file (or a screenshot of whatever tool your registrar uses to edit it) it will be easier to verify.

Comment: I added the snapshot. Im sorry but I could just not understand the whole Idea of naked domains.

Comment: @TusharMathur It says "Welcome to express" (expressjs application) when I access it. Looks correct to me then?

Comment: I am not able to see it from my system. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: @TusharMathur probably your browser or dns cache. Or a proxy server somewhere.

Comment: What is the solution ? Wait some more for them to get refreshed?

Comment: Probably. Try googling for instructions how to clear your browser cache and dns cache. But it also probably works for most other people.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29236/discussion-between-tushar-mathur-and-nilsh)

Comment: Tried incognito and cleared dns cache. Still its not working.

Comment: Hey! I got it now - actually I had to write www.tusharm.com What is that but ?

Comment: That is the "naked" part of the domain, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492563/heroku-godaddy-send-naked-domain-to-www for a description and solution