# How to setup custom domain names with Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, dns

I am attempting to follow the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) from Heroku to add a custom domain name for my Ruby on Rails application. In my CLI I have added the domain and it is viewable when I run heroku domains:

The Domain Name points to my address and the DNS Target points to my Heroku App address.

Inside my domain registrar, (GoDaddy), I set the CNAME to my Heroku address. The domain has propagated for enough time and it just displays that it is being parked when I access it.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Do you paid heroku ssl ?

Comment: @Gearnode No I have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar problem with Godaddy except I was also dealing with not only forwarding www.something.com to my herokuapp but also the something.com forwarding to the same app (without the www).

Here's what I suggest you do

Check in your heroku settings under domains you have something like this

```
   domain_name: www.something.com    DNS_Target: something.herokuapp.com
   domain_name: something.com        DNS_Target: something.herokuapp.com
```

On Godaddy, under domain details > settings, make sure your forwarding looks like this

```
    Forwarding:   Domain: http://something.herokuapp.com/(forward only)
```

Now under the DNS Zone file make sure you have a CNAME (Alias) record that looks like this below ... ps. this section has a (page 1 of 2) pagination at the bottom of the CNAME section if you don't see your record it could be on the next page

```
  host: www   points_to: something.herokuapp.com   ttl: 600 seconds
```

now the important part is under your A (Host) records you need to change the `@` host to point to a this exact ip address ...

```
  host: @   points_to:   174.129.25.170   ttl: 600 seconds
```

when i dealt with this problem, [this SO question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492563/heroku-godaddy-send-naked-domain-to-www) helped me do that ^ which solved my issues. Especially the @ points_to that ip address

Comment: I added the DNS host as you specified and it works. The @ host was unchanged. Where can I access the IP from Heroku?

BTW - this is what happens I assume without pointing to the IP, it tells me the certificate is not secure on the domain.

"The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.herokuapp.com, herokuapp.com (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)"

Comment: @JonathanMusso Did you solve the certificate problem? I am trying to configure GoDaddy with Heroku and I get always forwarded to the heroku domain.. thanks Fabrizio