# How do I avoid this domain forwarding issue with Godaddy where subdomains accumulate?

Tags: dns, domain-forwarding

I have domain forwarding enabled since my site is hosted on Heroku.

I have one forward configured this way

```
example.com -> https://www.example.com
```

This puts in the **www** subdomain and has worked pretty well for several years. I'm setting up a staging server that I would like to access via

```
https://staging.example.com
```

I have pointed staging.example.com to the proper place at heroku, however when I enter

```
https://staging.example.com
```

it forwards to

```
https://www.staging.example.com
```

and there is a DNS unfound error.

Is there a way to accomplish this other than domain forwarding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku/GoDaddy: send naked domain to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492563/heroku-godaddy-send-naked-domain-to-www)

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all. Basically my starting state (that the bare domain points to the www) is the state that the supposed duplicate is trying to get to. My questions is about how to avoid a repercussion of the setup.

Comment: Please excuse the comment then.

Comment: No worries @Divise . I understand the need for duplicate detection...

Comment: I gave you an upvote for visibility I hope your question gets answered soon.