# How do I change my hosting partner(netlify to heroku) with big rock?

Tags: heroku, web-hosting

I have a website hosted on netlify. But I have built a new website which is hosted on heroku. So I need to change the hosting partner to heroku for my domain bought from big rock.I tried some ways but its linking to old website itself.

I have added the domain name (www.domainname.com) in heroku and changed the cname in big rock. But it isnt working. Do I need to change anything?

Comment: Double-check your records and wait for DNS propagation time.

Comment: It's been a week I have changed the cname. But no change. Do I need to change name servers?

Comment: Follow this guide, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#summary-of-steps . For root domains you need to do additional things. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492563/heroku-godaddy-send-naked-domain-to-www