# I have to pay for Custom-domain SSL on Heroku to get rid of the warning signs right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

I just want to make sure before I go purchase anything.

I have an app on heroku. The URL is myappname.herokuapps.com on cedar stack.

I purchased a custom domain on godady and set up CNAME to make the forwarding work. I am able to use my custom domain to access the app on heroku. The problem is that, I get the browser warnings on FF, Chrome, IE, etc. The message is below:

This is probably not the site you are looking for!
You attempted to reach www.mydomain.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.herokuapp.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of www.mydomain.com.
You should not proceed, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.

My questions are:

1. I need to purchase a SSL to fix this right?
2. Do I need to get a wildcard certification or do any of them work?
3. Any recommendations on where to purchase it? I saw some options such as RapidSSL, SSL Endpoint add-on on Heroku, etc.

Answer (score 2):

NO! You probably just didn't configured properly. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170664/how-to-configure-heroku-application-dns-to-godaddy-domain) you can check the steps. You probably didn't get the addon for custom domains.

Comment: I'm reading through your link and I added zerigo DNS... after I configure that, all I need to do is run 'heroku addons:add custom_domains:basic'?

Comment: looks like the custom domains addon no longer exists. I will look more into zerigo DNS

Comment: Hm. Did you run `heroku domains:add`?

Comment: Seems to me that it's free now :o No need for addon. The custom domain got merged on the heroku command line tool. So that's what you are missing. You must run the command to add your domain.

Comment: Yea I already had the custom domain working. I re-did everything just now anyway. What I was originally asking was about the security warning when I type in mydomain.com into the browser. It leads to the correct place but those security warnings about security certificates with the "HTTPS://" crossed out in red X in the address bar. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: Oh. If you want to use https you need som SSL cert. I though you wanted simple http

Comment: No, I just want simple http. I did already run heroku domains:add for www.mydomain.com as well as mydomain.com. I'm just trying to get rid of the security warnings so that visitors don't get scared off

Comment: After doing research, it appears that I need to pay $20/month to get rid of these securities warnings even though I just want simple http. Is that right? I followed all of the steps and everything works just fine, except these certificate warnings

Comment: Are you sure you are not pointing to https? Because those warning just appear when you do so. Maybe in your dns config you are telling it to use ssl.

Comment: I am forwarding mydomain.com to `http://www.mydomain.com`. I just set up zerigo, deleted all DNS entries on godaddy to re-add them, and removed then re-ran heroku domains:add... not sure what else to do after this. Hopefully this works

Comment: Yeah, don't forget dns stuff needs time to take effect

Comment: For anyone who finds this in the future, be sure to check in your production.rb    config.force_ssl = false

Answer (score 1):

The ssl add-on is only required if you want to use SSL and https. You should be able to browse  to http://mycustomdomain.com/ without getting a warning. Going to https://mycustomdomain.com/ will yield the warning unless you add the ssl add-on and a certificate for the domain.