# How to live Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, web-hosting

I am new user for website developer`(rails3.2)` and I don't know how to hosting over website to live.

I have used heroku but over website is not searchable by google and heroku added there domain i.e. `http://example.herokuapp.com` but I want website with `http://www.example.com`.

Please suggest me what process I have to follow. Please explain step by step.

Need paid server

Comment: so you have to use a paid server, i guess that!

Comment: heroku supports custom domains - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains - costs a monthly fee, but might be your best bet

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is a PaaS (Platform as a Service). There is no easier way to deploy application on the Cloud.
There are several domain configurations available to your app. Most simple is to add custom domains on Heroku `heroku domains:add www.example.com` and the next step, you must configure your application’s DNS to point to Heroku.

Becareful, DNS changes can take several minutes to several days to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to purchase a domain from any of the Domain provider(Go Daddy,Zerigo DNS).

And you need to point out your Heroku app configurations at Domain C-panel.

Here is an article at Heroku. have you checked it?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Also here are some few URL's that gives you some basic Idea.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns
[How to configure heroku application DNS to Godaddy Domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170664/how-to-configure-heroku-application-dns-to-godaddy-domain)