# DNS and custom domains on Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns

I have seen this answer: [How to configure heroku application DNS to Godaddy Domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170664/how-to-configure-heroku-application-dns-to-godaddy-domain). I am using 1and1, not GoDaddy. The docs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains do not specifically mention the need for an add on. My custom domain does point to my home page on Heroku, but the links from the home page to other content get a 500 error, and only the mydomain.herokuapp.com shows up in the url, not the domain I paid for.

What is the CURRENT way this is supposed to work, why/how, and how do I get it so ALL pages on my site ONLY show my domain, not ...herokuappp.com? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add your custom domain to your Heroku app (via `heroku domains:add <domain>`)? Does your custom domain have a CNAME record that points to `yourapp.herokuapp.com`? Is your app possibly re-directing to the `yourapp.herokuapp.com` domain?

Comment: @elithrar: Add custom domain in Heroku: Yes. CNAME: I think so. 1&1 does not have a display that uses words like CNAME, etc. The panel simply says to redirect your domain by pointing it to the current url, which is 'mydomain,herokuapp.com'.  App redirecting: I don't think so. I don't have any redirects set up on my app. Also, I selected the pointdns addon, but now the pointdns home page itself gives me nothing but 500 errors...

Comment: Re-direction is your problem: your console is *re-directing* to `yourapp.herokuapp.com`, hence why you see that instead of your own domain. This part of the Heroku article covers the specifics: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-subdomains - and this article on the 1&1 help centre covers how to set a CNAME: http://help.1and1.com/domains-c36931/manage-domains-c79822/dns-c37586/enter-a-cname-record-for-your-domain-a643600.html

Comment: @elithrar: Since I pointed the domain to pointdns, 1and1 says I can't see any of that cname, etc. stuff. But I don't see anyway to do it on pointdns, either. What a mess. I have support tickets in to both Heroku and PointDNS. If it isn't resolved soon I'll go back to 1and1 nameservers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Heroku has nothing to do with this. It is 1and1 dashboard complexity probably, I am sure there is somewhere a setting for CNAME.

Comment: Wow, @nerijusgood, I'd forgotten all about this until I got your comment. It was almost a year ago, after all. But you are correct, I finally got it fixed on the 1and1 end.

Comment: Hello, @MalikA.Rumi how do you fix it ?