# How to mask a herokuapp using a GoDaddy domain

Tags: heroku, web-deployment

I'm using my url: `usetreehouse.com` from GoDaddy to forward to heroku.

However, I want to mask the .herokuapp part of the forwarding. For example it goes from example.com -> example.herokuapp.com and I want to get rid of the herokuapp.com in the domain. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure heroku application DNS to Godaddy Domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170664/how-to-configure-heroku-application-dns-to-godaddy-domain)

Comment: This is more about masking your heroku app domain with your purchased domain permanently in the address bar so when viewers go to www.example.com they arent shown www.example.herokuapp.com. Have this same issue. still looking for a solution.