# Heroku + GoDaddy configuration

Tags: heroku

I am having trouble configuring my domain with Heroku and Godaddy. I made a custom domain using the domain name I bought which generated;

```
www.example.herokudns.com
```

Then I head over to Godaddy and select;

```
CNAME 
Host -> www
points to -> example.herokudns.com
```

Now it works but not without the

```
www
```

So I create a custom root domain

```
 heroku domains:add example.com
```

but no examples are given for Godaddy.  So how do I configure my domain to get "without www" to work?  Thanks

Comment: Well I got it to work using the forwarding option in Godaddy.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: Forwarding isn't ideal. See if this helps you out... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170664/how-to-configure-heroku-application-dns-to-godaddy-domain