# Why will my DNS not direct to my Heroku app?

Tags: django, heroku, dns, godaddy-api

I have a Django application I have built and deployed on Heroku.  I have a custom domain I wish to use for my Heroku application.  The application works perfectly on the [herokuapp URL](https://dinpodcast.herokuapp.com/), but the [custom URL](http://www.dinpodcast.com/) doesn't seem to be working at all, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the custom domain as set up on Heroku.  You'll notice I blacked out the DNS target, that may not have been necessary, I just am unsure if that is something that is sensitive as I am still a bit of a noob at all this:

[image]

I have added the DNS information as a CNAME on my Godaddy DNS Management:

[image]

I can guarantee the DNS Target on Heroku perfectly matches the DNS Data on Godaddy.  The one and only difference between the two strings is the "." that godaddy appends at the end of the data.  Despite the fact that everything looks just right to me, I've waited plenty of time for the DNS servers to propagate, I still get this error when I got to http://dinpodcast.com

[image]

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: The domain is able to be pinged. Can you confirm this is the right IP? `15.197.142.173` (This is going to be a public facing website, giving out it's IP should not be an issue.) `http://www.dinpodcast.com:80` gives an empty response error.

Comment: That is the IP for my domain in GoDaddy, yes.  It is listed as an A record with the name "@", that's what I should be looking for, correct?

Comment: Looks like I got it to work by adding www at the beginning of my custom domain name in Heroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added in heroku *dinpodcast.com* and not **[www.dinpodcast.com](http://www.dinpodcast.com)**.

Repeat the entire procedure with the correct domain name, and remember to add your domain in the ALLOWED_HOST in the settings.py

Comment: I have made this change and am going to give the change some time to propagate.  Now, I'm getting "This site can’t be reached; Check if there is a typo in www.dinpodcast.com."  Help me understand though, it looks like the solution to this person's problem was exactly the opposite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170664/how-to-configure-heroku-application-dns-to-godaddy-domain

Comment: Ah, it works now!  Thank you!  Still a little unsure why that other question had the opposite answer though...